# Tumblr posts underlapping sidebar after Disqus installation?

Tags: html, css, tumblr, disqus

I'm pretty clueless with code but somehow managed to fix an issue with my Disqus comment box by following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489987/remove-disqus-comment-box-from-main-tumblr-page-but-keep-comment-boxes-for-each) instructions. My Disqus comment box is now only on my posts, which is what I wanted, but now my posts are underlapping the sidebar, making them unreadable. Please, explain how to fix this issue like I'm five because I just started fiddling with HTML today.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you copied the code following the instructions and placed it in an incorrect position. google how to recover a tumblr theme then copy and paste the code all over again. Make sure that you do not delete any code in the process.